# Why should i define frame to display UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

When I defined image that way :

```
var imageView : UIImageView
imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:10, y:50, width:100, height:300))
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"Test.jpeg")
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

it works well and the image appears on the screen, but why should I define frame? Why when I just defined center parameter image does not appear on the screen? ( During init imageView knows its height and width and I just adding center point to view)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. 
It is one of possible options.

You can initialise it with default init:

`UIImageView()`

or with image:

`imageView  = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"Test.jpeg")!)`

But mind that there is a plenty of options to display the image: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode

Comment: According to your offer(suggestion) imageView won't appear on screen anyway

Comment: Definitely you had to add it to view hierarchy. And in case of UIImageView() it has zero size, sou you need to provide proper constraints / set up frame.

Comment: And in case of UIImageView() it has zero size <----- But when i print after all imageView.size it print valid size. It seems when i print size this guy knows it, but when its time to apply constrains and so on he neatly forget it...(((

Comment: depends on constraints,  content mode, etc. What constraints you are setting up?

Comment: profileimageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

Comment: Do you have proper autoresizing mask?

Comment: UIViewAutoresizing(rawValue: 0) is there a problem?

Comment: no even if i set autoresizing mask it is don't appear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

No , imageView don't take it's true size as width and height , you should use frame layout to give it size or autolayout , unless you first init it with image

Comment: where it noted?

Answer (score 0):

If you init a `UIImageView` with an image, then you are right, the frame is set according to the image size. But in your code snippet you init the `UIImageView` with a frame and set the image later, which preserves the view frame. As an alternative, call `sizeToFit` after setting the image.

Comment: If you init a UIImageView with an image, then you are right, the frame is set according to the image size. Well if it does and UIImageView without a frame  then why image don't appear on screen?

Comment: @N.Khasanov If the UIImageView's frame size is zero, you just don't see the image.